# vba formulaR1C1 concatenate from different columns with function

Tags: vba, concatenation, formula

I'm getting error for the following code: Application-defined or object-defined error.

How do I fix this?

p.s. lastRow is a number

```
Range("A2:" & "A" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[6],RC[7],RC[9],RC[10],RC[11],ROUND(RC[12],0),IF(RC[13]="",0,RC[13]),ROUND(RC[14],2),YEAR(RC[15]),MONTH(RC[15]),DAY(RC[15]))"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `""` need to be `""""`

```
Range("A2:" & "A" & 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[6],RC[7],RC[9],RC[10],RC[11],ROUND(RC[12],0),IF(RC[13]="""",0,RC[13]),ROUND(RC[14],2),YEAR(RC[15]),MONTH(RC[15]),DAY(RC[15]))"
```

Comment: @Audrey please come back in a few minutes and mark correct.

Comment: how about this?       Range("C2:" & "C" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(A:A,RC[-2])"    apparently A:A is wrong